# sum of months like jan=Jan and feb =jan+feb using mysql and march = jan+feb+march

Tags: mysql

My query is I have Name column, Amount column, month column.

example if name is Sandeep he is having amount 90 in month Jan
like below

```
Name    Amount   month new column
Sandeep  90      Jan    Jan(amount)=90
Sandeep  100     Feb.    (jan+feb)amount=190
Sandeep  120     March  (jan+feb+march)=310
Mandeep  70      April   (0+0+0+April)=70
Mandeep  20      May      (0+0+0+70+20)=90
```

I want the new column with the same format as above using MySQL query

Comment: Its not a good idea to store the month as a string. Even I don't know, what if the next year starts? will you erase all you old data because the amount of jan this year will otherwise be the amount of next year?

Comment: So when there's a new month, it should add a new row for every name where the amount is the sum of all the previous amounts for that name?  I'm a little unclear what the end result should be

Comment: Sorry there is another column called year where it will be shown year

Comment: Why does sandeep not appear in april and may? Also it's best to show sample data in tabular form.

Comment: Hi Jonathan yes as you said it's right @JonathanClark

Comment: @P.Salmon because it is null.

Comment: What is null in this context? and what if sandeep missed in april and paid in may , or is that not possible?

Comment: @JonathanClark each name has values based on month so I want a column like if sandeep has jan value then the column should show jan amount,

Comment: @JonathanClark if he is having feb then the new column should have jan+feb amount

Comment: If you change the `month` column to be numeric, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql) to calculate running totals. Doing it with names will be harder, but you can use the [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

Comment: then the may column should e like jan+feb+march+april+may as april has no amount it will be 90+100+120+0+something will be the column

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a complete other approach.

Store your monthly data in one row per name. Make your data an Integer containing Year and Month

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    yearmonth INT,
    amount INT
);

INSERT INTO t (name, yearmonth, amount) 
    VALUES ('Sandeep', 202101, 90),
           ('Sandeep', 202102, 100),    
           ('Sandeep', 202103, 120),    
           ('Mandeep', 202104, 70), 
           ('Mandeep', 202105, 20);
```

Then you can easily request all data you need
For example:

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount)
FROM t
WHERE name = 'Sandeep' AND yearmonth BETWEEN 202101 AND 202103
```

I have created a little fiddle for you.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gZ1u7yB65FddjfKLU92tHE/0