# Mysql cumulative count query

Tags: mysql

I was just trying a cumulative query in mysql but unfortunately  didn't produce the desired result.Basically needs to group a result the query   by months  while cumulatively counting open tickets in a support portal.

for example.An expected result when querying.

```
month  open tickets  
1       5
2       8 (3 from this month and 5 from month 1) .
3       10 
4        7.  only 2 new tickets and 5 from previous months  were closed.
```

The complexity arises when you want to exclude a ticket if it change the status  over the period.
if a ticket was open for the entirety of month one and closed in month 2  it will count for month one but should not be added on to month 2 or subsequent months.

Query tried.

```
select month(date) as month,
       (select sum(if(statusid = 1) # 1 for open tickets.
        from tickets t2 
        where t2.date <= last_day(t1.date)) as TotalCount
from tickets  s2
group by month
order by t2.date
;
```

however this one does not exclude the tickets if they have changed status.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're missing the 2nd and 3rd argument to `IF()`.

Comment: Please add sample data that produces the expected result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393586/1491895 for how to compute a running total using window functions instead of the correlated subquery.